# How to set conditional blocks in Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need to set 3 conditional blocks in Apache `mod_rewrite`: one for `/api-docs` another one for `/api` and a third one for everything else. But I can't find what I'm doing wrong as I can't make it work as described.

So far, I have set the file `.htaccess` as follow:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} api-docs
RewriteRule (.*) api-docs/$1 [C]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} api
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ server/api.php/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html
```

But I get the error:

```
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.
```

Apache and system version:

```
 Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/7.2.7
```

Can anyone help me to find the error, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the solution after deep dive into Apache Documentation. The main saver was the `END` flag (see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end) along with other changes you can find in the final result.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "api\/.*"
RewriteRule ^api\/(.*)$ server/api.php/$1 [END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=api\/.*
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

I hope this helps to people who works with Angular 2+ and wants to use the same Apache server for both backend and and SPA at the same time.